# Java Script navigation not working?

Tags: javascript, navigation

I want to make a navigation bar in JavaScript on my website so I only have to edit one file when I want to add a new page to my website. After looking up tutorials I found one that does almost what I want however even this one doesn't work.

```
function nav(String url)
{
window.location.href = url;
}

<form>
<input type="button" value="Home" onclick="nav(http://www.atsbusinessandgames.co.cc/)" />
</form>
```

However this won't show up in my navigation bar. Also I want it to look like any other link and not be a button if possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're only using JavaScript so you only have to edit one page, why not use some type of server-side language to include a navigation bar from a separate file instead?

Comment: @icktoofay Because I don't know how. Right now my navigation bar is in html. Can I link to a HTML navigation bar written in html and use it within a div. I use a separate CSS file could I add it in there maybe.

Comment: If you're using Apache and have [Server-Side Includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) on, you could use them: `<!--#include file="navbar.html" -->`. For more information about Apache's support of it, you can see [its documentation on it](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html).

Comment: @icktoofay I'm using MySql with php.

Comment: Even easier! Put a `nav.php` file or something with your navigation bar in it and call `require("nav.php");` wherever you want your navigation bar.

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking Java, you don't specify the type in function parameters in JS.

```
function nav (url) {
  window.location.href = url;
  // or window.location = url;
  // sometimes window.location.href = ...
  // behaves in a funny manner cross-domain.
}

<form>
  <input type="button" value="Home" onclick="nav('http://www.atsbusinessandgames.co.cc/');" />
</form>
```

Oh, and, apologies, should also note the single-quotes around the url.

Comment: Opps. I was working on this right after I got done in my AP computer science class which is Java. However this still hasn't changed anything. The navigation bar still doesn't show at all.